# Combobox with Column Values based on Field Value

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm making a combobox, that shows a key identifier, and the summary.

[image: Here's a mockup of source data].

So I've got cases where there's an Epic (2), and a Story (3), with the same Parent ID. I've also got cases where there's a story (5) with a parent ID (4), that isn't in the table.

I want to create a two column combobox that looks like this
[image: looks like this].

I want the first column, my bound column, to only show each Parent ID once. In cases like Parent ID 2, where there is both an Epic and a Story, I want the second column to show the Summary of the Epic. But in cases of Parent ID 4, where ID 4 doesn't exist on my table as it's own record, I want to have Summary populate with the summary of ID 5.

I'm totally lost on how to do this in SQL.

`SELECT table.[Parent ID], First(table.[Summary]) As [Summary]`

is about as far as I've gotten, but that just returns the first Summary for a given Parent ID, whether that record is Type Epic or Story.

I've been stumped on this for a while, any help is most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
SELECT ParentID, Summary FROM Table3 WHERE ID IN (
    SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM Table3 AS Dupe 
    WHERE Dupe.ParentID=Table3.ParentID ORDER BY Dupe.Type);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is where [GROUP BY](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) comes into effect.

```
SELECT ParentID, MAX(Summary)
FROM Table3
GROUP BY ParentID
```

But that is only part of the picture, because you will lose the 'Once Told Me', as it's alphabetically less than 'The World'.

If you need to see all Summary then this may help:

```
SELECT ParentID, Summary, MAX(Type) AS [Type], COUNT(*)
FROM Table3
GROUP BY ParentID, Summary
```

Comment: The second has circular reference error. I fix that and output is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, I think the following does what you want by prioritizing the Epic:

```
select parentid,
       nz(max(iif(type = "Epic", summary, null)),
          max(summary)
         )
from t
group by parentid;
```